# { n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 } when updating array too fast in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code in controller.ts. It's a basic function that deletes a task

```
export const remove = catchErrors(async (req, res) => {
  const task = await Task.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
  await task?.deleteOne();
  res.respond(task);
});
```

I created a hook on deleteOne for tasks so that it would update the taskList and remove the objectId from there as well

```
taskSchema.pre("deleteOne", { document: true }, async function () {
  const that = this as ITask;
  const taskList = await TaskList.findOne({ _id: that.list });

  if (taskList) {
    await taskList.updateOne({ $pull: { tasks: that._id } });
  }
});
```

as you can see here taskSchema has a property that refers to a particular tasklist

```
const taskSchema = new Schema({
  task: { type: String, required: true },
  list: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "TaskList", required: true },
});
```

and tasklist has an array that is a collection of tasks _id

```
const taskListSchema = new Schema({
  date: { type: Date, require: true },
  tasks: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Task",
    },
  ],
});
```

Everything is working fine if i delete the tasks slowly on the client side. If I delete them fast, updateOne in the hook **sometimes** return `{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`, because of this the task is deleted but the array in the tasklist is not updated. I also tried to put the updateOne directly in the controller instead of relying on hooks but I am getting the same result.

I've been trying to figure out why this is happening for days but I could not find an answer. I'm tempting to move to postgres because of this issue but maybe I could get an answer here. If it helps, I am using mongoose.